# Regex to find matching string in a ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I have this string in ruby, I want to find the contract_addendum_1 key and its value, Can someone please tell me the regex to find the contract_addendum_1 with its value.

```
"{\"month_day\":\"JulyYork\",\"state\":\"NY\",\"zip\":\"10104\",\"country\":\"US\",\"investment_id\":102,\"inve,\"contract_addendum_1\":\"Pursuant to the Side Letter re: Assignment dated [June__, 2021 ] between Security\\n Sponsor 2021-1, LLC herein as \"Subscriber\", and FTF Lending, LLC herein as \"Borrower\" so be it\\n acknowledged that Subscriber purchased this Non-Recourse Borrower Payment Dependent Note and\\n immediately transferred all of it's right,set forth to US Issuer hey 2021-1\\n herein as \"Holder\". [Lawyers to add any additional wording if needed].\",\"subscriber_name\":\"Security Sponsor 2021-1, LLC\"}"
```

I tried on https://rubular.com/
so far this is what I came across `\\"contract_addendum_1\\":\\"([^"]+)` but this is incomplete, since it does not match to the end of the value.

Comment: Your string looks JSON. Unfortunately, it is misformed. Where is that string coming from? Would you be able to fix it?

Comment: It's coming from the database, which can't be fixed. so that's why I need a regix to find the key

Comment: Actually, this isn't even a valid string

Comment: Is this a result you get when printing the string? It is incorrectly escaped as is - the quotes around words like Holder, Borrower and Subscriber are not escaped.

Comment: sorry I updated the string.

Comment: @BroiSatse please check it again the string is updated.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does not solve my problem

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the solution only finds half of the value, not the full value, please check the output again and compare it with the value in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the double quotes are not serialized correctly in this JSON-like string.

To solve this correctly, you need to contact the JSON provider and ask them to fix this on their side.

As a dirty fix, you can match any chars between `"contract_addendum_1":"` and the leftmost occurrence of `","`+one or more word chars+`":`, or end of string (which is viable in case the broken JSON ends abruptly in the middle of the value):

```rb
s="{\"month_day\":\"JulyYork\",\"state\":\"NY\",\"zip\":\"10104\",\"country\":\"US\",\"investment_id\":102,\"inve,\"contract_addendum_1\":\"Pursuant to the Side Letter re: Assignment dated [June__, 2021 ] between Security\\n Sponsor 2021-1, LLC herein as \"Subscriber\", and FTF Lending, LLC herein as \"Borrower\" so be it\\n acknowledged that Subscriber purchased this Non-Recourse Borrower Payment Dependent Note and\\n immediately transferred all of it's right,set forth to US Issuer hey 2021-1\\n herein as \"Holder\". [Lawyers to add any additional wording if needed].\",\"subscriber_name\":\"Security Sponsor 2021-1, LLC\"}"
puts s[/"contract_addendum_1":"(.*?)(?:","\w+":|\z)/m,1]
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/ufGToo).

Output:

```rb
Pursuant to the Side Letter re: Assignment dated [June__, 2021 ] between Security\n Sponsor 2021-1, LLC herein as "Subscriber", and FTF Lending, LLC herein as "Borrower" so be it\n acknowledged that Subscriber purchased this Non-Recourse Borrower Payment Dependent Note and\n immediately transferred all of it's right,set forth to US Issuer hey 2021-1\n herein as "Holder". [Lawyers to add any additional wording if needed].
```

*Regex details*:

- `"contract_addendum_1":"` - a fixed, literal string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more cchars as few as possible
- `(?:","\w+":|\z)` - `","`, one or more word chars, `":` or end of string.

Answer (score 0):

If the String is valid JSON then

```
JSON.parse(string)["contract_addendum_1"]
```

Are you sure this is the full string as in the DB? because there is something wrong with it just before the "contract_addendum_1" key.

Depending on your DB you could even extract it directly.

Comment: Got error "unexpected token at" when parsing it. Can't we simply make a regex?

Comment: yes, because your JSON is not JSON. You can make a Regex but it is a hack.